# How to update kernel to specific version

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, updates

I would like to upgrade to specific kernel version (5.4.0-81-generic) from following current state on different servers.
I would like to use apt package manger to update kernel.

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS  4.15.0-55-generic
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS    4.15.0-51-generic
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS    4.15.0-20-generic
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS    4.15.0-106-generic
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS    4.15.0-133-generic
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS    4.15.0-140-generic
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS    4.15.0-107-generic
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS  5.4.0-74-generic
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS  5.4.0-77-generic

ls /boot
config-4.15.0-76-generic  grub                          initrd.img-5.4.0-70-generic   System.map-5.4.0-70-generic  vmlinuz-5.4.0-70-generic
config-5.4.0-70-generic   initrd.img-4.15.0-76-generic  System.map-4.15.0-76-generic  vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic

uname -r
5.4.0-70-generic
```

I get following 2 images when try to search for kernel version, which one to use.

```
apt-cache search linux-image | grep 5.4.0-81-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-81-generic - Linux kernel image for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Now, how to safely, gracefully update only the kernel version -

```
apt-get upgrade linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) It is already in [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/linux-signed-hwe-5.4). To keep your system secure you have to install security upgrades (not just only kernel).

Comment: My question is more on how to install specific kernel version using apt package manager.

Comment: Please add output of `ls /boot` and `uname -r` to the question.

Comment: added output of ls /boot and uname -r

Comment: You question should clearly explain exactly why you want a specific older kernel. It can be done, but it's a corner case. The explanation will help dissuade new users (the main frequenters of this site) from erroneously downgrading their kernels.

Answer (score 5):

**Warning: doing things below is dangerous if you care about system security. Proceed only if you are sure what do you want to achieve.**

So you have to remove [meta-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04) (it usually depends on the latest kernel, nowadays it is 5.4.0-86 in this HWE stack) by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then install fixed version by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic
```

**But please again note that latest kernel is safer, it may have many CVEs fixed. Check [changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.4/linux-hwe-5.4_5.4.0-86.97%7E18.04.1/changelog) for details.**

So to get all latest upgrades back you have to execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get all latest dependencies
```

and then reboot to use all latest software including the kernel.

---

More stuff to read:

- `man apt` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html), `man apt-get` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_-_Bionic_Beaver
- https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/package-management.html

Comment: Could you please let me know where did you find ` linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 ` and what it is and why it is to be removed.

Comment: I was looking at https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel which didn't say anything to be removed. what's the significance of removing meta-package, please let me know.

Comment: Packages like linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic are dynamic dependencies of linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 . Current is 5.4.0-86 .

Comment: Isn't my current kernel is '5.4.0-70-generic' as per uname -r command output and how is it related to removing met-package 'linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04' will remove my old package.

Comment: You have to understand dpkg/APT internals more carefully. Please read the relevant docs. Then execute `apt-cache rdepends linux-image-5.4.0-70-generic` to understand the relations between it and `linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04` package. You have to  learn tools and system before doing strange things, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I followed the steps and successfully installed 5.10 and 5.13.19 kernels on 18.04.6 LTS. I used mainline to install these kernels.