# Running Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210 adapter under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, kernel, iwlwifi

I want to get a Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX210 adapter running under ubuntu 18.04.
[This intel page](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) says that its only supported after kernel version 5.10 but like I understood from [here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Ubuntu_LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack_information), Ubuntu 18.04 is shipped with kernel 5.4 and I could not manage to get a newer kernel version installed.

Is it possible to install kernel 5.10+ on ubuntu 18.04 or is there any other possibility to get the AX210 adapter running?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Basically, it is here https://askubuntu.com/a/1320583. However, I cannot compile the git repo. Instead, I use the intel repo, see below.

First, install some necessary package

```bash
sudo apt install flex bison
```

clone the backport repo, compile and install it:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/intel/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
sudo make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sudo make
sudo make install
```

The above probably worked in January 2022, but a year later you can have a problem to compile. So you need a little modification to above instruction. After `cd backport-iwlwifi` go back to the older version of the repository and then open the sources:

```bash
git checkout 5b3f6ff8
cd iwlwifi-stack-dev
```

If you still have problems with compilation then apply this patch: https://www.spinics.net/lists/backports/msg05376.html (just edit manually `nano backport-include/linux/mod_devicetable.h` and add 4 lines before end):

```
--- a/backport/backport-include/linux/mod_devicetable.h
+++ b/backport/backport-include/linux/mod_devicetable.h
@@ -29,4 +29,8 @@ struct mhi_device_id {
 };
 #endif
 
+#if LINUX_VERSION_IS_LESS(4,17,0)
+#define DMI_OEM_STRING (DMI_STRING_MAX + 1)
+#endif /* < 4.17.0 */
+
 #endif /* __BACKPORT_MOD_DEVICETABLE_H */
--
```

Then go back to instruction: configure, compile and install.

Third, download the driver, or you can download your driver from Intel website.

```bash
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware/
sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
```

Reboot the machine and it works for me.

Comment: It works for me running ubuntu 18.04 on ASUS ROG strix 15 (2022)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution for this but I replaced the WiFi-adapter with a Intel-AX201, which is obviously supported, and it works.

Comment: I don't think this is the kind of answer we look for here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the AX210 supported on 18.04 unless the Kernel team backports a 5.10+ kernel to that release, which is not likely given that it has not been backported already.  The closest thing to work with would be upgrading to 20.04 and using the HWE stack there that includes the 5.10.x kernels.

Answer (score 0):

On my 18.04.6, I upgraded the kernel to 5.13.19 and copied the driver from Intel website to /lib/firmware. It worked like a charm after that.

For upgrade I followed the instructions here and used mainline to install the specific kernel version:

[How to update kernel to specific version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366063/how-to-update-kernel-to-specific-version)

Intel driver downloaded from here (unzip and copy iwlwifi*.ucode file to /lib/firmware):

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html