# Ubuntu 20.04.3, networking card 3168NGW. Slow (~1Mbps to ~10Mbps) wifi speeds

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I have decided to do a reinstall from my current 20.04 system which has perfectly working internet. I am experiencing slow wifi speeds (~10Mbps) using Ubuntu `20.04.3` after the reinstall. Trying from other computers running the same versions of Ubuntu I am getting ~1Gbps speeds. `dmesg` is throwing the following error:

```
[  510.017019] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Queue 11 is active on fifo 1 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [89, 58] HW [89, 58] FH TRB=0x0c010b068
[  510.018083] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[  510.018242] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  510.018245] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[  510.018250] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode
[  510.018254] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  510.018259] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00800634 | trm_hw_status0
[  510.018262] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  510.018265] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00043D6C | branchlink2
[  510.018269] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x0004AFA2 | interruptlink1
[  510.018272] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x000251A0 | interruptlink2
[  510.018275] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[  510.018278] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[  510.018281] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[  510.018284] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x0FC11859 | beacon time
[  510.018286] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0xF515C9DC | tsf low
[  510.018289] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x0000000E | tsf hi
[  510.018292] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  510.018294] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00A106F8 | time gp2
[  510.018297] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  510.018300] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[  510.018303] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x62A39462 | uCode version minor
[  510.018305] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000220 | hw version
[  510.018308] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[  510.018311] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x0B59001C | hcmd
[  510.018313] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0xA4022002 | isr0
[  510.018316] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[  510.018318] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x0000000A | isr2
[  510.018321] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x0041E8CD | isr3
[  510.018323] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  510.018326] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x004A019C | last cmd Id
[  510.018329] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[  510.018331] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[  510.018334] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00012030 | l2p_duration
[  510.018336] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[  510.018339] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_addr_match
[  510.018341] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000005 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  510.018344] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x16070617 | timestamp
[  510.018346] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00347880 | flow_handler
[  510.018356] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  510.018363] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  510.018370] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  510.018377] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  510.018384] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  510.018392] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  510.018398] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  510.018405] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  510.018412] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  510.018419] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  510.018426] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  510.018433] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  510.018440] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
```

Pinging something mundane like google.com leaves me with 85% packet loss. I believe this is because the firmware is crashing every other second.

I am currently running the following kernel:

```
taylorswift2013@box:~$ uname -a
Linux box 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have the following wifi adapters:

```
taylorswift2013@box:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 10
       serial: 40:ec:99:53:79:29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode ip=192.168.20.148 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:68 memory:fcc00000-fcc01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 03
       serial: a8:a1:59:3b:c6:b8
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=0. 4-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:38 memory:fcb00000-fcb1ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:fcb20000-fcb23fff
```

I am attempting to get things working on hardware of `Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]`

This seems to be a common problem. I have tried the following solutions

1. Attempting to reinstall `iwlwifi` drivers (https://askubuntu.com/a/1388993/1566940). Although when checking the driver versions with `md5sum` they do not seem to be corrupted as the checksums match my other machine)
2. Moving to an earlier `iwlwifi` firmware version (`29` downgrade to `27`) (https://askubuntu.com/a/1389357/1566940) to no effect
3. Using `11n_enable=0` in modprobe configuration for `iwlwifi.conf`. This increased my speeds from ~1Mbps to ~10Mbps, this is not an acceptable speed though because of the ~1Gbps speeds all my other devices run at. Furthermore disabling 802.11 is a workaround not a solution
4. Upgrading kernel with `sudo apt upgrade --upgrade` which bumped up my kernel version to the above version. No changes
5. Using ethernet connection on motherboard, no changes
6. Using a usb-c to ethernet adapter instead of motherboard. 10x increase to ~100Mbps which is still well shy of ~1Gbps I'm observing from other devices
7. Resetting my CMOS doesn't do anything
8. Updating BIOS to latest stable version doesn't do anything (4.60) (https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/fatal1ty%20b450%20gaming-itxac/index.asp#BIOS)
9. Trying 21.10 ubuntu, no change
10. Tried a memtest from 21.10 live usb. Bunch of memory errors that I think are caused by my motherboard. Seems to be a hardware problem. I will replace both motherboard and RAM

Could this be a hardware problem? I've been trying to get this working for a day and am at the point where I'm thinking I should just replace a 300 dollar motherboard because I'm losing productivity

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? What processor? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @guiverc. Sorry it's the 20.04.3 version. I've upgraded the kernel using the method I've described in the post above.

Comment: @heynnema

`taylorswift2013@box:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

`P3.70`

Comment: My motherboard is a ASRock b450 Gaming-ITx/ac . I'll see if there are any bios updates available

Edit: There are some updates available. I'll try updating

Comment: Updating the bios to the latest version (https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/fatal1ty%20b450%20gaming-itxac/index.asp#BIOS) 4.60 did nothing

Comment: @heynnema . Nothing is overclocked. Running a ryzen 2600  and motherboard is ASRock b450, Minimal ubuntu 20.04.3 install

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live 21.10 USB and retest. Also go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete. Report back.

Comment: I'd really rather be on LTS but I'll try both and get back

Comment: Tied 21.10, no change. Doing a memtest from grub yielded a bunch of of memory errors. I think it's my actually my motherboard that is the problem and will go about replacing it, might replace both memory and motherboard. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll put together a quick answer, and maybe you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

```
ASRock B450 Gaming-ITx/ac
Ryzen 2600
```

After a lot of troubleshooting, without success, we ran `memtest` and it found a bunch of problems.

Don't replace the motherboard just yet. You have a Ryzen processor. They're very fussy about RAM. Go to the ASRock web site and check on the compatible memory list to see if your DIMMs are listed. Also make sure they're spec'd correctly for your MB.

First check the **CPU Support List** to determine your processor family, then review the appropriate **Memory QVL** list.

https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/fatal1ty%20b450%20gaming-itxac/index.asp#CPU

https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/fatal1ty%20b450%20gaming-itxac/index.asp#MemoryPR

Replace the RAM as necessary.