# Ubuntu 20.04: Wireless Disappears Randomly

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, intel, iwlwifi

A while after getting a new router, I started experiencing a problem with wireless networking on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop. When I turn it on, it detects my wireless network and connects to it.

However, the connection breaks soon after I log in, or after a few hours. Sometimes, I need to restart Ubuntu three times until I get a seemingly stable connection.

When I lose the connection, I can't even see the Wireless (WIFI) option in the settings.

This isn't my field of expertise, so I'd appreciate it if anyone would help me.

Here are the logs and outputs of some commands. Note that I'm currently using a wired connection and that I got these logs and outputs after the wireless connection broke.

**Operating system:**

```
uname -a
Linux xxx 5.13.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 2 23:37:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Networking hardware:**

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-usb:1                   
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor
       vendor: ICS Advent
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: enx00e04c534458
       version: 1.01
       serial: 00:e0:4c:53:44:58
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: usb-1.10 ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=dm9601 driverversion=5.13.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 Ether ip=192.168.1.5 link=yes maxpower=120mA multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ef100000-ef101fff
```

**dmesg:** the logs are in the [pastebin file](https://pastebin.com/GE0VJxvy).

**The [wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205):**

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 16 Jun 2022 10:25 CEST +0200

Booted last: 16 Jun 2022 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.13.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 2 23:37:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a11 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0fe6:9700 ICS Advent DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04d9:a06b Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Wireless USB Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                421888  0
mac80211             1028096  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               372736  1 iwlmvm
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              888832  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
asus_wmi               36864  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    32768  5 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  53248  3 asus_wmi,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: anbox0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'anbox0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.250.1/24 scope global anbox0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'anbox0' [IF1]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
       valid_lft 259073sec preferred_lft 259073sec
    inet6 fe80::e3c8:d3de:991f:a1a5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

anbox0    no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto dhcp metric 20100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev anbox0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.5 metric 100 
192.168.250.0/24 dev anbox0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.250.1 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        1061       1  1 10:21 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         ICS Advent
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         dm9601
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.13.0-48-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 Ether
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ddad471b-4e56-3ee2-a74d-15eecf8d404a
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.5/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 20100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 259200
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1655626999
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.5
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e3c8:d3de:991f:a1a5/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/12
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ddad471b-4e56-3ee2-a74d-15eecf8d404a | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         anbox0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBridge
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'anbox0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/anbox0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       anbox0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     anbox0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       8cc8ce19-18fa-4c76-9688-42dddd810147
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.250.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.250.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'anbox0' [IF1]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
BRIDGE.SLAVES:                          --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/11
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   8cc8ce19-18fa-4c76-9688-42dddd810147 | anbox0

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D0_04_B0_50_98_A2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/10
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   9f55da1a-f11e-4207-90a5-27dacf039d2d | Galaxy A52s 5G Network

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ZTE_H168.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ZTE_H168 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ZTE_H168
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SBB Zona.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SBB Zona | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SBB Zona
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TS-h4dZ.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TS-h4dZ | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TS-h4dZ
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/M mreza.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=M mreza | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=M mreza
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HUAWEI-B311-230A.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HUAWEI-B311-230A | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HUAWEI-B311-230A
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MIWIFI_2G_cQXb.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MIWIFI_2G_cQXb | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MIWIFI_2G_cQXb
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Telenor-Internet-E5.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Telenor-Internet-E5 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Telenor-Internet-E5
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HP-Print-5C-Deskjet 3540 series.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HP-Print-5C-Deskjet 3540 series | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HP-Print-5C-Deskjet 3540 series
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Fokus.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Fokus | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Fokus
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Belgrade (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

anbox0    no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

anbox0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlmvm
vermagic:       5.13.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-48-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.13.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.13.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-48-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.13.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
enable_ini: Y
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   79.111201]  ? __iwl_err.cold+0x25/0x2a [iwlwifi]
[   79.111368] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwl_trans_wait_tx_queues_empty bad state = 0
[   79.111382] wlp2s0: failed to remove key (1, <MAC address>) from hardware (-5)
[   79.212274] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   79.212361] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[   79.212407] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
[  118.171881] dm9601 1-3:1.0 eth0: register 'dm9601' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 Ethernet, <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
[  118.211446] dm9601 1-3:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed from eth0
[  118.290596] dm9601 1-3:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xFFFF
[  119.949226] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link becomes ready
[  119.972111] dm9601 1-3:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xFFFF (repeated 2 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

**When WiFi is working**, I get this output for `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: a4:c3:f0:95:cf:e0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-48-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 memory:ef100000-ef101fff
```

Comment: Please note from the log: "iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?" I suspect this is a hardware issue. Please try removing and reseating the wireless card from its slot. After restarting, check the log again: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @Milos Can you please update with this situation? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, @VinRaghav. I eventually ran into another problem soon after chili555's suggestion about reseating the wireless card (unfortunately, I didn't have time to try it). The operating system couldn't load and there were boot problems even after a clean re-install. There were also faulty disk sections. So, I bought a new laptop. Hopefully, you'll have more luck. :)