# WIFI - Intermittently disconnects

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, internet, iwlwifi

Not too sure about the issue causing the wifi to intermittently cut off and reconnect - seems like there's an issue with the queue but can't make sense of the rest of the information provided by `dmesg`.

Ubuntu 18.04.6

**Kernel:** 5.6.17-050617-generic

`lspci` dump:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b44 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc4 (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 06f9
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 06ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 06ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 06f0
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 06e0
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 06e3
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b8 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06be (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bf (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b0 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 068e
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 06c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 06a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 06a4
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
06:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
2c:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
53:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation Device 7560 (rev 01)
54:00.0 SD Host controller: Genesys Logic, Inc Device 9755
55:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
```

`dmesg` dump:

```
[605970.064183] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 4 is stuck 34 136
[605970.064337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[605970.064421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[605970.064424] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[605970.064427] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.13675109.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
[605970.064430] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[605970.064433] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[605970.064435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[605970.064437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CA218 | branchlink2
[605970.064439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004B5208 | interruptlink1
[605970.064441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004B5208 | interruptlink2
[605970.064443] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00006870 | data1
[605970.064445] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF000000 | data2
[605970.064447] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
[605970.064449] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0DC04CAA | beacon time
[605970.064451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x89E9B6C9 | tsf low
[605970.064453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000081 | tsf hi
[605970.064455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[605970.064457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x38C9D67F | time gp2
[605970.064459] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[605970.064461] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | uCode version major
[605970.064463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x13675109 | uCode version minor
[605970.064465] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000351 | hw version
[605970.064467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00489004 | board version
[605970.064469] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8004FC04 | hcmd
[605970.064471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80020000 | isr0
[605970.064473] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[605970.064475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08F0000A | isr2
[605970.064476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C1FFCC | isr3
[605970.064478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[605970.064480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x005C019C | last cmd Id
[605970.064482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00006870 | wait_event
[605970.064484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[605970.064486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[605970.064488] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[605970.064490] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_addr_match
[605970.064492] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[605970.064494] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[605970.064496] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000058F8 | flow_handler
[605970.064537] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[605970.064540] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
[605970.064545] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[605970.064549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[605970.064552] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008D49C | umac branchlink2
[605970.064556] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8048DBE6 | umac interruptlink1
[605970.064561] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8048DBE6 | umac interruptlink2
[605970.064563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[605970.064565] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8048DBE6 | umac data2
[605970.064567] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[605970.064569] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[605970.064571] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x13675109 | umac minor
[605970.064573] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x38C9D676 | frame pointer
[605970.064575] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886284 | stack pointer
[605970.064577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x005C019C | last host cmd
[605970.064579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[605970.064598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[605970.064618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE0000101 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[605970.064640] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00290033 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[605970.064663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80070043 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[605970.064666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[605970.064686] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[605970.064690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[605970.064709] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[605970.064713] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[605970.064733] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[605970.064738] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[605970.064763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[605970.064791] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[605970.064919] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
[605970.064931] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[605970.549277] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[605970.694215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

Comment: `dmesg` is telling you there's an error with the microcode, the rest of that output is debug information to help [a developer] find the problem. https://askubuntu.com/a/1389357/29073 should work; or try upgrading/downgrading `linux-firmware`; or fallback to earlier kernel; or remove `QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode` to fallback to earlier firmware. Perhaps upgrade to a newer Ubuntu!

Comment: Thanks @pbjh will give it a try ^^ appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade `firmware-iwlwifi`, and the kernel if possible.

Or if it used to work earlier, downgrade to it.

Are you by any chance trying to connect to a 5 GHz network? If yes, probably the driver is buggy for it.

Try adding `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwl.conf`. Or the following:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
options iwlwifi swcrypto=0
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
options iwlwifi power_save=0
options iwlwifi uapsd_disable=1

options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
```

Courtesy: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1918843#p1918843